# One program with all necessary modules

Tags: python, windows, user-interface

I have a GUI and it is using PyQt5 and Python 3.6... I create this GUI by .exe format with `pyinstaller`  When I click the .exe file it works correctly and succesfully.  But How can I do the all what I need module and packet include onefile. For example there is another computer (Windows) havent any python3.6 and pyqt5 how can I install this module and packet just one click.

Comment: Is there any another advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller or not, you can create some form of `requirements.txt` (in fbs it is usually structured in `./requirements/base.txt` (with `mac.txt` and `windows.txt` as more specialized, platform-specific flavors to supplement the `base.txt` file).

This is currently my workflow to build & distribute fbs/PyQt5/python36 apps for macOS and win10, and collaborate with others who need to stay up-to-date & version-tied with various python libraries.

Besides, having all dependencies specified in `./requirements/base.txt` is better/built-in project portability & documentation. Use the `*.txt` file like this: `pip install -r ./requirements/base.txt`

An example `.txt` looks like this:

```
fbs
PyQt5==5.9.2
PyInstaller==3.4
google-cloud-storage
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[pyinstaller](/questions/tagged/pyinstaller)[fbs](/questions/tagged/fbs)[dependencies](/questions/tagged/dependencies)[documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation)[cross-platform](/questions/tagged/cross-platform)

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used [fbs](https://build-system.fman.io/) for that very purpose, you can give it a try.

Comment: I have examined it a bit, it used NSIS with windows and it doesn't install modules like python3.6 and pyqt itself when I create an installation file with it.

Comment: @gogogo Right, it doesn't. What it does is packing all of the necessary modules inside the installation file and once you install it you are getting a fully-featured standalone windows program with everything that it needs already packed in it. All the user has to do is simply launch it from the start menu as your any other windows program.